# File upload open while a checkbox is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, file-upload

I want to open a file upload when i checked a check box. In my aspx page containing a check box and a file upload. file upload control visible status is false. Now i want to open the file upload dialog box when i check the check. Please help me to do this..

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chk1" runat ="server" />
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" visible="false"  />

    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: I am new for .net am using file upload normally. But I can't this.

Comment: You mean **show**, not open. Those are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [OnCheckedChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.oncheckedchanged.aspx) event.

eg.

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" 
            oncheckedchanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True"/>
```

and in the code behind

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //open file upload
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For example you can add onclick event

```
onclick="document.getElementById('<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>').click(); return false;"
```